# CSS custom link underline in a responsive site not behaving as I would like

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a responsive website using Bootstrap 3 framework.
I'm using an image as a custom underline for my links (in a hover state).
The image is 3 small dots/circles next to each other.
I want the custom image to be centered under the link. It works fine when looked on full-width 
desktop screen. (I have made the image the same width as the links, that is 2 columns wide). The moment I make the screen smaller the underline image falls out of centered alignment with the links. Thanks for any advice, I'm fresh here so can't post photos...

Here's my HTML:

```
  <div class="row" id="navbar">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#about">about</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#services">services</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#team">team</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#contact">contact</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><a href="#clients">clients</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#navbar {
text-align: center;
color: #02161b;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 30px;
font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;}

#navbar a {color: #02161b;}

a:hover:after {
content: url(../img/navunderline165.png);
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 16px;}
```

Comment: Can you add a working jsfiddle example of this?  I don't see anything responsive about what you just posted so it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Also, why do you need to use a pseudo element?  Why not use a background image on the anchor itself?  Give the anchor some padding-bottom then, on hover, set the background image to `bottom: 0; left: 50%;` and it should have the desired effect, no?

Comment: Hi Eli, can't provide jsfiddle as I have my index.html, the massive bootstrap.css (which is making the website responsive) and my custom.css with which I am using to override the default bootstrap.css. If I add the background image to the anchor itself it is always visible (I want it visible only in case I hover over the link). How do I achieve that? Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what it is you want, but I;m guessing something like this:

CSS

```
#navbar a {
    color: #02161b;
    position: relative;
}
a:hover:after {
    content: url(http://familytrees.genopro.com/hoevenaren/images/trees32.gif);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86SgP/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the property:

```
position: absolute;
```

from

```
a:hover:after
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LtJ8/)**

### o/p

[image]